# Prove that E(X) exists if and only if E(|X|) exists.

Tags: probability, random-variables

I found this theorem in a book, but there is no proof there:

If X is a random variable, then
**Prove that E(X) exists if and only if E(|X|) exists.**
where $E(X)$ is the expected value of $X$

I know that if $E(|X|)$ exists, then that means that $E(X)$ converges absolutely, which in turn it means then $E(X)$ converges.

But how would I prove the other direction, that if $E(X)$ converges, so does $E(|X|)$  ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Lebesgue theory, one defines $EX$ as $EX^+ - EX^-$, where $X^+=\max \{ X,0 \}$ and $X^-=\max \{ -X,0 \}$. Thus the condition is really that $EX^+$ and $EX^-$ are both finite, in which case both $EX$ and $E|X|=EX^+ + EX^-$ exist and are finite.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't know anything about "Lebesgue theory", so I wonder is there any other simpler way ?

Comment: When I said "Lebesgue theory", I meant when one uses the Lebesgue integral rather than the Riemann integral. One cannot study modern probability theory without the Lebesgue integral, for a variety of reasons. At any rate, when one defines integration using the improper Riemann integral, the result in your question is not true. For example, if $X$ is uniform on $[0,1]$ and $Y=\sin(1/X)/X$ for $X \neq 0$ and $0$ for $X=0$, then $EY$ exists but $E|Y|$ does not. (This is just the fact that $\sin(x)/x$ is not absolutely integrable over $[1,\infty)$ in disguise.)

Comment: Thanks. But what if X is a discrete random variable?

Comment: In Lebesgue integration there's no difference; the expectation of a discrete random variable is an integral against a discrete measure. Though if $X$ takes on finitely many values then of course $EX$ and $E|X|$ exist.